# Are there any laws in Australia that would stop someone having a doorbell that captured fingerprints

Tags: australia

Technology to capture fingerprints is becoming common. One could imagine a doorbell that logs and stores fingerprints of every person who uses the bell.

Are there any laws in Australia that would prevent a doorbell like this being used?

Answer (score 1):

### The [Privacy Act 1988](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_Act_1988)

Where it applies - Federal & ACT government entities , companies providing health services and companies with annual revenue greater than $3 million. Similar state law applies to state government entities. Also, it doesn’t apply to employees of the organization.

There is no restriction on private persons or SMEs (Small and Medium Enterprises).

If it applies, the data could only be collected for a legitimate purpose.

Comment: Specifically what about the privacy act?  My understanding is the privacy act only allows you to collect information you need or is there something else